# ZF2 MongoDB ODM authentication

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine-odm

i m doing ZF2 MongoDB ODM authentication but getting the error "An exception was raised while creating "doctrine.documentmanager.odm_default"; no instance returned" and "Drivers must specify a class" i m using the configuration from the [ZF2 MongoDB ODM authentication Tutorial](http://pastebin.com/JKRM6P4u)
[image: error 1]
[image: error 2]

any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have done two things to do it.
1-i have solved it by changing the Drivers path as it was not assigning.

```
'odm_driver' => array(
    'class' => 'Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
    'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Document')
),
'odm_default' => array(
    'drivers' => array(
    __NAMESPACE__ . '\Document' => 'odm_driver'
    )
)
```

2-then i made two objects of getUsername and getPassword in the user Admin/Document/user

```
public function getUsername(){
    return $this->username;     
}

public function getPassword(){
    return $this->password;
}
```